# Adjust the find_all() expression to find images as well

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm using the following `find_all()` expression, to get
all the NavigableStrings, sorted in the normal flow.

```
all_nav_strings = [x for x in node.find_all(text=True) if x.strip() != "" if not type(x) is bs4.Comment]
```

I'd like to adjust the `find_all()` expression to find all the images (in the normal flow order) as well.

I tried
`find_all([text = True, img = True])`

Answer (score 0):

This should get all elements in `node` if they are images or contain any text :

```
all_nav_strings = [ 
    tag for tag in node.find_all() 
    if (tag.text.strip() or tag.name == 'img') and not type(tag) is bs4.Comment 
]
```

A more elegant solution ( if you like lambdas ) using a `lambda` in `find_all` :

```
all_nav_strings = node.find_all(
    lambda tag: (tag.text.strip() or tag.name == 'img') and type(tag) is not bs4.Comment
)
```

Use `recursive=False` if you dont want `find_all` to get all child tags in `tag`

Comment: Your find_all() expression is evaluated as conjunction and according to this, it returns [], because <img> hasn't inner text. I'm looking for disjunction.

Comment: Ok, i misunderstood the question, updated my answer.

Comment: I'd like the result list to contain NavigableStrings and/or Tags with name "img" sorted in the normal flow. No need to write algorithm here - I'm only interested if bs4 is able to express it with the find_all() or similar method.

Comment: I can't think of a simpler solution for this task. You can use a list in `find_all` , eg: `find_all(['img', 'a'])` but that won't be useful in this case.

Comment: Thank you for trying. I don't know it as well, only to go through the parsed tree with a few while and for cycles - but this is not what I'm curious. Maybe, someone will surprise us.

Comment: Maybe. I've seen some amazing answers answers on this site. I wouldn't hold my breath though..